# how can I mock webclient a uri twice with different ids (same uri and different variables)

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spring-webflux, webclient

I have this webClient mock and it works if I only mock single ID. but here I will have a procedure that calls two different accounts and do some stuffs so I need to call a webClient twice like the blow code if this code works I'll be able to write the main test.

```
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
@AutoConfigureWebFlux
@SpringBootTest(classes = Application.class)
class AccountServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private AccountServiceInterface accountService;;
    @Mock
    WebClient webClientMock;
    @Mock
    WebClient.RequestHeadersUriSpec requestHeadersUriSpecMock;
    @Mock
    WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec requestHeadersSpecMock;
    @Mock
    WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpecMock;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(accountService, "webClient", webClientMock);
    }

    private void mockAccount(Long accountId){
        AccountGradeDto mockAccount = new AccountGradeDto(accountId, 1L, 1L, new BigDecimal(1000), AccountStatus.ACTIVE, 10L);

        when(webClientMock.get()).thenReturn(requestHeadersUriMock);
        when(requestHeadersUriMock.uri("/api/account/management/v1/get-account-grade/{id}", accountId)).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpecMock);
        when(requestHeadersSpecMock.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpecMock);
        when(responseSpecMock.onStatus(any(), any())).thenReturn(responseSpecMock);
        when(responseSpecMock.bodyToMono(AccountGradeDto.class)).thenReturn(Mono.just(mockAccount));
    }

    @Test
    public void testAccountService() {
        mockAccount(1L);
        mockAccount(2L);

        StepVerifier.create(accountService.getAccountById(2L))
                .expectNextMatches(account -> account.getId().equals(2L))
                .verifyComplete();

        StepVerifier.create(accountService.getAccountById(1L))
                .expectNextMatches(account -> account.getId().equals(1L)) //TEST FAILS HERE AS IT RETURNS SAME OBJECT
                .verifyComplete();
}
```

and here is the service implementation

```
@Service
public class AccountServiceImpl implements AccountServiceInterface {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    public AccountServiceImpl(@Value("${app.resource.account.service-base-url}") String baseUrl) {
        this.webClient = WebClient.create("http://" + baseUrl);
    }

    @Override
    public Mono<AccountGradeDto> getAccountById(Long accountId) {
        return webClient.get()
            .uri("/api/account/management/v1/get-account-grade/{id}", accountId)
            .retrieve()
            .onStatus(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND::equals, clientResponse -> Mono.empty())
            .bodyToMono(AccountGradeDto.class).transform(ReactiveUtils::errorIfEmpty);
    }
}
```

when I run the test if fails at second match (id: 1L) as it returns the same objects mocked for ID 2

Answer (score 1):

we should not use singleton scope for mocking `WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec` and `WebClient.ResponseSpec` and need to be mocked for every request on same uri.

```
private void mockAccount(Long accountId){
    AccountGradeDto mockAccount = new AccountGradeDto(accountId, 1L, 1L, new BigDecimal(1000), AccountStatus.ACTIVE, 10L);

    WebClient.ResponseSpec responseSpecMock = mock(WebClient.ResponseSpec.class);
    WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec requestHeadersSpecMock = mock(WebClient.RequestHeadersSpec.class);

    when(webClientMock.get()).thenReturn(requestHeadersUriMock);
    when(requestHeadersUriMock.uri("/api/account/management/v1/get-account-grade/{id}", accountId)).thenReturn(requestHeadersSpecMock);
    when(requestHeadersSpecMock.retrieve()).thenReturn(responseSpecMock);
    when(responseSpecMock.onStatus(any(), any())).thenReturn(responseSpecMock);
    when(responseSpecMock.bodyToMono(AccountGradeDto.class)).thenReturn(Mono.just(mockAccount));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mocking WebClient could be very tricky and error-prone. Even if you could cover some simple positive cases, it would be very hard to test more complex scenarios, like error handling, retries, ...

I would recommend [WireMock](https://wiremock.org/) which provides a very good API for testing web clients. Here are some examples

```
stubFor(get("/api/account/management/v1/get-account-grade/1")
        .withHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, containing(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
        .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withStatus(200)
                .withBody(...)
        )
);

StepVerifier.create(service.getAccountById(1))
        .expectNext(...)
        .verifyComplete();
```

You could easily test both positive and negative scenarios by providing different stubs

```
stubFor(get("/api/account/management/v1/get-account-grade/1")
        .withHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, containing(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE))
        .willReturn(aResponse()
                .withStatus(500)
        )
);
```

or test retry logic using [Scenarios](https://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/) or even simulate timeouts using [Delays](https://wiremock.org/docs/simulating-faults/)